# Rest controller is not accepting UTF-8 special characters in POST request body in spring boot

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, utf-8, character-encoding

Rest controller is not accepting UTF-8 special characters in POST request body in spring boot.
Giving below error:

`JSON parse error: Invalid UTF-8 middle byte 0x6f; nested exception is com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException: Invalid UTF-8 middle byte 0x6f`

I have added below mapping in my controller

```
consumes = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_UTF8_VALUE
produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_UTF8_VALUE
```

In header I have added below:

```
application/json; Charset=utf-8
```

and in application.properties I have added below options as well

```
server.servlet.encoding.charset=UTF-8
server.servlet.encoding.force-response=true
server.servlet.encoding.enabled=true
server.servlet.encoding.force-request=true
spring.mandatory_file_encoding=UTF-8
```

but did not work.

```
my spring boot version = 2.1.3.RELEASE 
Java version = 1.8
```

I have added below property in POM.xml

`<project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>`

If any body could provide any solution:

Comment: I don't know this API but it looks like it is receiving corrupt content. Check that content

Comment: content is fine and API works fine , but it is not accepting special characters like ñ, Á,
Â, Ä, Æ, Ç, È,É

Comment: Take the very first of the above characters *only*. What is the error message with `ñ`?

Comment: As far I can read from the error, the API want UTF-8, but you are not giving it a valid UTF-8 string. So check and encode properly the string. -- PS: declaring UTF-8 in all places, doesn't make a string UTF-8. Check that your data is UTF-8

Comment: if it could relate to spring boot version, because I tried a new POC with spring boot version 2.2.6.RELEASE. It worked. It accepted the UTF-8 chars with out any property addittion.